# EasyMock / Arrays.asList(...) with only one varagrs parameter

Tags: java, easymock

We recently switched from Oracle JDK 8 to OpenJDK 11 and I've encountered a strange behavior in the following case:

```
final List<Interface> foo = Arrays.asList(EasyMock.mock(Interface.class))
```

I'm getting the following exception when run in a unit test via JUnit:

class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy225 cannot be cast to class [Lorg.example.Interface; (com.sun.proxy.$Proxy225 and [Lorg.example.Interface; are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

EasyMock version is the newest (4.0.1).

For sure I should have used `Collections.singletonList(...)` and this is also what compiles and runs or now since Java9!? `List.of(...)`, but yeah.

I don't really get the problem, but I think it's related to EasyMock with Java 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type inference issue. It's caused by the new way EasyMock does type inference. It helps tremendously in many cases but here is an example where it won't be able to cast to the right type.

The solution is to use a type witness. This will work: `List<Interface> foo = Arrays.asList(EasyMock.<Interface, Interface>mock(Interface.class));`

Comment: Another one seems to be generic classes.